# how to put output php on a specic place

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have made two divs besides each other, the left div contains a list of names and in the right one is empty.

The names in the left div are generated from a database, also it's wrapped into a a tag so I can click on it.

```
echo "<a href='Overview.php?id=" .$row['ID']  . "'>" .$row['COMPANY']."&nbsp;</td> <br>";
```

When somebody clicks on the a tag it will generate a new variable: id in the browser link.
Now my main goal is to get this $row['ID'] variable into the right div.

What I tried (php function):
If the ID is set (= somebody clicked on the a tag) it will echo the id. But I have no clue how to place this into the right div (#rightcolumn)

```
function runMyFunction() {
   echo $_GET['id'];
  }

  if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    runMyFunction();
  }
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Please post the `html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so call your function in right div

```
<div id="rightcolumn"><?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) {runMyFunction();}?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery or javascript

```
echo "$('#rightcolumn').html(".$_GET['id'].");";
```

or

```
echo "document.getElementById('rightcolumn').innerHTML = ".$_GET['id'].";";
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone already posted a solution for PHP.
But you can also consider using JQuery and fire an on click event :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <a href="#" id="Id1">Name1</a><br>
    </div>
    <div class="right">

    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#Id1').on('click', function(){
   var id = $('#Id1').attr('id');
    $('.right').text(id);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, will definitely try this out